Automate Print/Export Excel Worksheet to PDF
I have an Excel sheet which updates automatically when someone completes a MS Form. Data from the form runs through Power Query and a worksheet called Feedback gets updated.
I want to then print the entire worksheet (Feedback) to PDF and save to a SharePoint site.
I can do all of this manually and via a Macro. The task though, is to automate this so I don't have to open the workbook and run through macro.
My attempt was to use Power Automate. The action to Convert a File works fine BUT only when I manually copy the Feedback worksheet into a new workbook (it errors when the whole workbook is selected in the flow). Is this the best way, or is there a way to bypass the need to copy the worksheet into a new book, say by Exporting/Printing to PDF via Office Scripts?

Unfortunately, Office Scripts doesn't support the ability to export/print to PDF. I'd recommend posting your question in the Power Automate community to help troubleshoot why your convert file action is failing on the original workbook. Sorry that I can't help more!
